# When working with AppHarbor, how can I properly manage development and live configuration files?

Tags: git, asp.net-mvc-3, version-control, configuration-files, appharbor

I have a small project under way, in which I'm experimenting with [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/). For those of you who aren't familiar with it, AppHarbor allows you to automatically build and deploy ASP.NET MVC projects in the cloud, by adding a specific Git remote and then pushing your project/source to that remote.

The way I'm currently working is that I'll have a master Git repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/), which I clone to my development machine. I then add the AppHarbor remote to my working copy. I'll make my changes, push to GitHub every few commits for safe-keeping, and when I'm ready to deploy a new version I can just push it up to AppHarbor.

While this is a great workflow, it brings up a new problem for me concerning configuration files. What I used to do is to exclude `Web.config` from source control and instead check in a file called `Web.config.example`, which contained all the correct keys but with dummy values. I would then simply make a copy of that file on my dev machine, remove the `.example` extension and edit the values to suit.

When it came to deployment, I'd create another copy called `Web.config.live`, replace the values with the correct ones for the server, upload it and remove the `.live` extension.

The problem I have now is that if `Web.config` is *not* under source control, when I push to AppHarbor, the project won't work (because it's lacking the proper configuration information). Yet I don't want the live connection string publically viewable on GitHub, which it would be if I ever pushed `Web.config` to the master repo.

What are my options here? I'd be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AppHarbor supports replacement of configuration variables on deploy to avoid the problem of committing usernames and passwords to source control (amongst other uses). It's [documented in the knowledge-base](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/managing-environments).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, though I'm still slightly confused about exactly how I would use this. The way I understand it, I would add a `Web.config` containing the connection string I use on my _development_ machine to my Git repo, then when I push to AppHarbor it will automatically replace that connection string with the live connection string (as long as they are identically named). Is this correct?